# mysql_connect() issue

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to connect to Mysql database with following Php code. But I get 2 error message.

**Mysql Connect Code:**

```
<?php
define("HOST", "localhost" );
define("USER", "root");
define("PASS", "");
define("DB", "classified");

mysql_connect("HOST", "USER") or die("Cannot connect to database");;
mysql_select_db("DB") or die("Cannot connect to select db");
?>
```

**Error Message:**

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host   
is known. in D:\Software\Installed\xampp\htdocs\Classified-website\toplevel\content
\database\databd.php on line 7

Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host 
is known. in D:\Software\Installed\xampp\htdocs\Classified-website\toplevel\content
\database\databd.php on line 7

Cannot connect to database.
```

Why I get this 2 error message. If i use without define function then it's working. BUT..

Comment: Also stop using the mysql_ functions. They are outdated and deprecated.

Comment: Please also start reading a manual before asking: http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the quotes from 
`mysql_connect("HOST", "USER")`

To
`mysql_connect(HOST, USER)`

As they are defined constants - if you use the quotes, it's taking HOST and USER as a string literal.

Comment: `mysql_select_db("DB")` shall also be `mysql_select_db(DB)`

Comment: Yea, I hoped that OP would be able to infer that from my answer :-)

Comment: OH! @Darrrrrren It's working..I forgot to use of php define(). Thank you.

Comment: @Darrrrrren I don't think that you should remember Babu after 30mins! Your answer also lags a link to mysqli functions. But an accepted answer reduces the chance of a better answer...

Answer (score 2):

You are not supposed to use quotes around hostname and db name.

Try: `mysql_connect(HOST, USER)` instead of `mysql_connect("HOST", "USER")`. Try same thing for db name.

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 2):

You don't wrap CONSTANTS with double quotes:

**Instead of:**

```
  mysql_connect("HOST","DB");
```

**Use:**

```
  mysql_connect(HOST,DB);
```

Same things apply for all constants.
**Also:**    Drop using mysql functions, because they are not safe enough. Instead use **MySQLI or PDO**. I would prefer  **PDO.**